# IDE em Cloud para desenvolvimento C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ide, cloud

Alguém conhece alguma IDE em *cloud* para desenvolvimento em C# ASP.NET?
Li alguma coisa sobre uma CODERUN, mas acho que não está mais ativa, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Acho pertinente essa pergunta, vou acompanhar as respostas!

Answer (score 4):

A Microsoft possui [um pre-release de algo que vai ser uma IDE em Cloud no futuro](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2609774/cloud-computing/microsoft-reinvents-visual-studio-as-an-azure-cloud-service.html), mas ainda não está pronto até a data desta resposta.

O Coderun sumiu da face da terra. O código dele deveria estar em dois lugares: Codeplex (que não existe mais) e [Google Project](https://code.google.com/p/coderun/source/checkout) (que está vazio).

Comment: Muito chato esse fato de tirar do ar do nada, sem justificativas.

Comment: @DiegoSantos, isso cheira a conspiração corporativa, imagino que alguém pagou um bom dinheiro para desaparecer com o código.